# Rubygem uses wrong dependencies during `elasticsearch-transport` installation

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fluentd

When I'm installing `elasticsearch-transport` for td-agent I'm getting following error after `td-agent-gem install elasticsearch-transport -v2.0.0.pre` command:

```
/opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling system_timer_native.c
In file included from system_timer_native.c:8:0:
/opt/td-agent/embedded/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward/rubysig.h:14:2: warning: #warning rubysig.h is obsolete [-Wcpp]
 #warning rubysig.h is obsolete
  ^
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘install_first_timer_and_save_original_configuration’:
system_timer_native.c:43:22: error: storage size of ‘timer_interval’ isn’t known
     struct itimerval timer_interval;
                      ^
system_timer_native.c:81:24: error: ‘ITIMER_REAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (0 != setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer_interval, &original_timer_interval)) {
                        ^
system_timer_native.c:81:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘install_next_timer’:
system_timer_native.c:108:22: error: storage size of ‘timer_interval’ isn’t known
     struct itimerval timer_interval;
                      ^
system_timer_native.c:129:24: error: ‘ITIMER_REAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (0 != setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer_interval, NULL)) {
                        ^
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘restore_original_timer_interval’:
system_timer_native.c:189:24: error: ‘ITIMER_REAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (0 != setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &original_timer_interval, NULL)) {
                        ^
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘install_ruby_sigalrm_handler’:
system_timer_native.c:211:5: error: ‘rb_thread_critical’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     rb_thread_critical = 1;
     ^
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘restore_original_ruby_sigalrm_handler’:
system_timer_native.c:217:5: error: ‘rb_thread_critical’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     rb_thread_critical = 1;
     ^
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘set_itimerval’:
system_timer_native.c:292:10: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     value->it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
          ^
system_timer_native.c:293:10: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     value->it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
          ^
system_timer_native.c:294:10: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     value->it_value.tv_sec = (long int) (seconds);
          ^
system_timer_native.c:295:10: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     value->it_value.tv_usec = (long int) ((seconds - value->it_value.tv_sec) \
          ^
system_timer_native.c:295:59: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     value->it_value.tv_usec = (long int) ((seconds - value->it_value.tv_sec) \
                                                           ^
system_timer_native.c:298:61: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
       log_debug("[set_itimerval] Set to %ds + %dus\n", value->it_value.tv_sec,
                                                             ^
system_timer_native.c:299:61: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
                                                        value->it_value.tv_usec);
                                                             ^
make: *** [system_timer_native.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Here's the output of `td-agent env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
```

It looks like that during installation gem is trying to install wrong dependency (system_timer) which should be used only if Ruby version is lower than 1.9 according to the [Gemspec](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/838b8d231f26152fccc436508835a2ac325d32ad/elasticsearch-transport/elasticsearch-transport.gemspec#L26). Actually when I downloaded the gem using `td-agent-gem fetch elasticsearch-transport -v2.0.0.pre`, unpacked it (`td-agent-gem unpack elasticsearch-transport-2.0.0.pre.gem`) and then built it again (`td-agent-gem build elasticsearch-transport.gemspec`) I got different set of dependencies:

```
$ td-agent-gem install elasticsearch-transport-2.0.0.pre.fetched.gem --explain
Gems to install:
  elasticsearch-transport-2.0.0.pre
  faraday-0.9.2
  multi_json-1.10.1
  multipart-post-2.0.0
  system_timer-1.2.4

$ td-agent-gem install elasticsearch-transport-2.0.0.pre.built.gem --explain
Gems to install:
  elasticsearch-transport-2.0.0.pre
  faraday-0.9.2
  multi_json-1.10.1
  multipart-post-2.0.0
```

How can I install this gem without building it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems elasticsearch-transport issue.
I filed a bug report on repository: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/issues/329

Comment: Thanks! I'm unfamiliar with Ruby environment and I didn't know that gemspec checks are interpreted only during `gem build`.